# How to store same name file in google cloud storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I am creating a website which has lots of user uploaded image files, So with the time it may happen link there will be same name images on Google cloud storage, Even one user can upload same name image over the time, So how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do is add timestamp to your filename while uploading

e.g.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$timeStamp = $date->getTimestamp();
$fileName = $fileName. "_" . $timeStamp;
```

And then when you are allowing user to download the file, read the file name and remove last part from underscore and give user link with this parameter in url with original final name

```
$service = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
$objects = $service->objects->listObjects($bucketName);

// Assuming first item you are downloading
$objects = $objects['modelData']["items"][0];
$filename = substr($objects["name"], 0, strrchr($objects["name"],"_"));
$url .= "&response-content-disposition=attachment;%20filename=.$filename"
```

Comment: Hi, I facing almost the same issue I used random UUID instead of time stamp, anyway I'm trying to serve the file to my users directly from cloud-storage, that will save me some headache but I can't do that while keeping the original fine name, any advice?

I tried making the UUID as a folder name and put the file in it, but still google is using the folder as part of the file name when downloading