# How to allow google cloud storage to save duplicate files and not overwrite

Tags: django

I am using google cloud storage bucket to save file uploads from my Django web application. However if a file with same name is uploaded, then it overwrites the existing file and i do not want this to happen. I want to allow duplicate file saving at same location. Before moving to google cloud storage when i used my computer's hard disk to save files, Django used to smartly update filename in database as well as hard disk.

Comment: following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25885048/11225821) you can add timestamp so the file name won't get duplicate

Comment: Since i am using Django integration with Google Storage, I don't have that choice i believe. I may be wrong but that's what i feel.

Answer (score -2):

I upload files with the name given by users, and I concatenate a timestamp including seconds and milliseconds. but the name of the file is seen by clients as they added it, since I remove that part of the string when it is displayed in the view.

example

image1-16-03-2022-12-20-32-user-u123.pdf

image1-27-01-2022-8-22-32-usuario-anotheruser.pdf

both users would see the name image1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).